# how to pass a custom query from google data studio to BigQuery using BigQuery connector?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have read the document of BigQuery connector(https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en).

I want to pass a custom query from data studio to Bigquery.

But I don't know where I should wirte the SQL code on the UI interface.

Is there any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Start New Report >> <kbd>CREATE NEW DATA SOURCE</kbd>  >>  Choose BigQuery in Connectors List  >>  Choose Project  >>  Enter Custom Query

Comment: Thank you! I  I misunderstood the document.

Comment: @Mikhail would you know of a way to pass custom parameters to these custom queries, e.g., a way of defining an ad-hoc date-range (for a custom aggregation) ?

Comment: Have u ever found a solution for the custom date-range?